# Memory leaks when calls dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have to show a couple of different cells. I called `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` for that, and in the method I use two different IDs for different classes of `UITableViceCell`

Here is a simple code:

```
class SimpleView: UITableViewController {
...

let cellIdMain = "JournalMainCellID"
let cellIdExtra = "JournalMainSceneAddNewID"

...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == journals.count {
        guard let cellAdding = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdExtra, for: indexPath) as? JournalMainSceneAddNew else {
            fatalError("Cannot connect to the cell")
        }
        return cellAdding
    }

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdMain, for: indexPath) as? JournalMainSceneCell else {
        fatalError("Cannot connect to the cell")
    }
    cell.numberOfCountriesLabel.text = "\(journals[indexPath.row].numberOFCountries)"
    return cell
}
}
```

When I tried to find memory leaks I found:

[image]

When I click on the details I found:

[image]

Why this happened? It looks pretty simple and straightforward.

Updated: pictures were updated.

Comment: It is, but the XCode point out at a different part of the code.

Comment: @matt sorry it is true. It is identical. Xcode shows 32 byte memory leaks for every row. I will update the picture.

Comment: @matt - then I use string value instead of `cellIdMain` or `cellIdExtra ` in   `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` it looks like memory leak disappear... Strange, all IDs is `let` constant...

Comment: I also tried to use `guard let cellAdding = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(cellIdExtra)", for: indexPath) else...` without any effect.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing if conditions which will work only in one case as indexpath.row will only be equal to count
even though it will not work because after going through if it will execute block of code after if
which means your if block is waste 
and why are you using cell.delegate??

Comment: The tableViewController should show the last row different. That’s why i use If contition. Delegate is need because of use swipecellkit external library. But the problem is memory leak, and it is in the `dequeueReusableCell` method. I don’t understand it

Comment: then write the rest in else part

Comment: it is better to use switch on indexpath.row, for case equal to journals.count and default only 2 cases will be there

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with the following code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == journals.count {

        let cellAdding: JournalMainSceneAddNew = {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdExtra) as? JournalMainSceneAddNew else {                
                return JournalMainSceneAddNew(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdExtra)
            }
            return cell
        }()

        return cellAdding
    }

    let cell: JournalMainSceneCell = {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdMain) as? JournalMainSceneCell else {                
            return JournalMainSceneCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdMain)
        }
        return cell
    }()

    cell.numberOfCountriesLabel.text = "\(journals[indexPath.row].numberOFCountries)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: then I use string value directly instead of `cellIdMain` or `cellIdExtra` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` it looks like memory leak disappear... Strange, all IDs is let constant...

Comment: yes, you can use directly string value as an identifier.

Comment: But why I can't use let constant of String in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` ?

Comment: I am going to read the swift doc again, but as far as I know it let constant and String class - here should not be any strong reference cycles

Comment: @Alex I'm facing the same issue. Did anything work for you?