# NSString initWithCoder, memory leak at DequeueReusableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-management, memory-leaks

Please read the full case before answering, there is a similar question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55501778/8192960).

With no actual answer.

The case is the following,

1.I have a `UITableView` that has 3 prototype `UITableViewCell` inside of it on the `UIStoryBoard`.
2.I use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)` in `CellForRowAt` delegate.
3.Using instruments and memory graph, the `dequeueReusableCell` function is causing a memory leak of type **Malloc**. where each cell is leaking **N** number of bytes of type `NSString`

The instruments profiling look like this.
[image]
And tracing each one of those **30** Malloc bytes it leads to this ( 1 for each cell).
[image]

Now What I have tried:

first I thought this issue is related to string used as identifier in the dequeueing the code looked like this

`guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TransactionHeaderCell") as? TransactionHeaderCell else { return UITableViewCell() }`
this is simple straight forward, however i saved the `cellId` in a `static var` to double check and the result was the same,

Second I implemented a generic dequeuing function something like this,
[image]
With no luck, therefore I doubt that its related to the way dequeue is implemented but more of something might be in the cell it self or in the `Foundation` kit that I don't get,

> Side Note: This might not be related but the `UIViewController` holding the `UITableView` is a part of `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have a leak and this is not just a false positive? If you keep scrolling your tableview back and forth and hence dequeueing cells for a couple of minutes, does the memory usage of your app actually grow constantly?

Comment: the more I scroll the more mallocs allocations I have, I did dequeue a 100 cell and the I had in the malloc count a 100 allocations, is that what you asking about ?

Comment: the size is 32 bytes so I would to dequeue a huge number to notice a memory increase but they're there, the more dequeue I do the more leak number I would have.

Comment: facing exactly same leak at my side. Was there any solution found?

Comment: Some sample code that exhibits the problem would help here.